# Latest Change not in ContentObserver

Tags: android, camera, android-contentresolver

When my ContentObserver is called because of a freshly taken photo, 
that freshest photo is nowhere to be found in a query.

I am registering my ContentObserver like this:

```
        getContentResolver()
                .registerContentObserver(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        false,
                        imageObserver
                );
```

Yet, the following callback can only query for the last image before that, not the newly taken image itself:

```
@Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "date_added DESC");
            String filePath = null;
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
```

What can i do to retrieve the real latest picture in the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

the second parameter has to be true:

```
getContentResolver()
                .registerContentObserver(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        true,
                        imageObserver
                );
```

That allows you to do the following:

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

Just don't forget to keep track of what ID you have already processed, since one photo may trigger multiple events...